# Whic representation of graph is preferred, anjacency matix or adjacency list?

Tags: algorithms, graphs

I have a graph in which vertices are 100 and edges are more than 300. If I want to represent this graph in either adjacency matrix or adjacency list, which graph representation will be preferred?

### My effort:

[I have read several articles.](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/graph-representation/a/representing-graphs) In this article, I have found that the comparison should be done in the following criteria:

1) Terms of space and time.
2) how long it takes to determine whether a given edge is in the graph?
3)  how long it takes to find the neighbors of a given vertex.

So for the above question, I have found an adjacency matrix is the best solution. Is my assumption is correct? Please enlighten me.

Comment: This is not answerable in the general case.  Preferred for what purpose?  An adjacency matrix might be preferable for some tasks, and an adjacency list might be preferable for other tasks.  Moreover, in many cases there is not a clear "preferred" but rather a set of tradeoffs (adjacency matrix is better in this way and worse in another way).  Finally, what is "preferred" might be a matter of opinion.  To make this answerable, please replace "preferred" with some specific objectively evaluatable criteria.

Comment: If the criteria is storage space, then because the average degree of a vertex is at most a fixed constant, adjacency lists would use lesser storage. If time complexity is the criteria, it depends on the algorithm which uses the data structure. If the algorithm checks a large number of times whether two vertices  are adjacent,  then the algorithm would run more quickly with adjacency matrices.  There are other kinds of operations where adjacency lists are faster.